# Document automatically scaling when I reduce the size of the window but not when I set to a mobile view port

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, bootstrap-4

I'm building a web app and have been trying to sort out some mobile first design, if I scale my chrome window down, the page is responsive and works well, scaling objects down to a suitable level.

However, when I set it to a mobile view-port (by clicking inspect-element and then clicking on the icon of a phone) the page does not scale down accordingly - how do I know what my page will look like on a mobile device? Will it be the same as when I scale down the page in the web browser window or will it be like when I open a mobile view-port?

Comment: Please post a specific example that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to add `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">` in `<head>`.

The default behaviour of mobile browsers is to act like a fairly big window, because non-responsive websites would freak out at the actual size of the phone. This tells the browser to use its true size instead.